# VBA Set Range With Blank Pivot Item

Tags: vba, range, pivot

I currently have the following code to set a range from my pivot table (the dataset is for regional income):

```
Set RngE1 = PT.PivotFields("Region").PivotItems("Europe").LabelRange
Set RngE2 = Intersect(PT.PivotFields("Region").PivotItems("Europe").DataRange.EntireRow, PT.PivotFields("Income").DataRange)
Set RngEurope = Union(RngE1, RngE2)
```

However this is a monthly report and in certain months there will be no income for Europe. As such, I would run into an error whereby the macro cannot get the LabelRange of the PivotItem class. Is there any code I can use that would skip this step if the LabelRange is not found, rather than break the macro?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its nasty but what about just an error trap?

```
Dim bTest as Boolean
bTest = False

' ----------
On Error Resume Next
Set RngE1 = PT.PivotFields("Region").PivotItems("Europe").LabelRange
If Err Then bTest = True
On Error Goto 0

If bTest Then
     'Handle here
Else
     'All good
End If
```

Comment: Would I need to do this for each and every line that contains "Europe", @DenzilNewman? I have quite a number of such lines!
What does the '0' do in the line 'On Error Goto 0'?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, its probably no help to you now.

on error resume next
ignores errors

on error goto 0
resumes normal error handling - I know thats not what it looks like